# Integral limit function - Exponential

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function

Do the integral $\frac{d}{dt} y(t) = -a \, y(t)^p$ converge to $y(t) = e^{-at}$ for $p \to 1$? I have tried to integrate and use l'Hospital rule, without success.

Formally, $\lim\limits_{p\to 1} Y(t, p) \stackrel{?}{=} e^{-at}$.

Best regards, 
Bruno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $y' = -ay^p$. Integrate separately, we obtain,

$\frac{y^{-p+1}}{-p+1} = -at + C$, where $C-$ an arbitrary constant. When $p \rightarrow 1$, we've a problem. Hence use L'Hopital's to evaluate limit of the term on LHS as $p \rightarrow 1$.

$\frac{d(y^{-p+1})}{dp}=-y^{-p+1} log(y)$. Hence $\lim_{p \rightarrow1} \frac{y^{-p+1}}{-p+1}=\lim_{p \rightarrow1} y^{-p+1}log(y)=log(y)$. Terms on RHS remain the same since $p$ is independent from $t$. So, $log(y) = -at + C$ which gives $y = Ke^{-at}$, $K-$ constant

Comment: I had trouble isolating y and seeing if the RHS expression would converge to $e^{-at}$. Could you try to do this way to explain in this manner?

Comment: That's what I did. 

Divide both sides of the equation by $y^p$. You've $y^{-p}  dy/dt = -a$. By integrating as a separable equation, you get,

$\frac{y^{-p+1}}{-p+1} = -at + C$. Then, $\lim_{p \rightarrow 1} \frac{y^{-p+1}}{-p+1} = \lim_{p \rightarrow 1} (-at +C) = -at +C$. So, the issue is the term on LHS as it is of indeterminate form. Apply L'Hopital rule to evaluate the limit, which is $log (y)$. 

Note that, we differentiate $y^{-p+1}$ w.r.t $p$ not $y$.

Comment: I have tried to do following: $y(t) = [-at(1-p)]^{\frac{1}{1-p}}$ and then take the limit. It does go well, although it should.

Comment: How do you evaluate $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} kx ^{1/x}$ (this is of indeterminate form. so you've to use L'Hopital's).

Your approach is fine but you've got to know how to use L'Hopital's to evaluate $(-at (1-p)^{1/{1-p}})$ as $p \rightarrow 1$ (i.e; as $p-1 \rightarrow 0$)

Comment: I tried applying the continuous function limit trick, but ended up in lim log(kx)/x, whose value tends to -infty on 0. :S. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You can evaluate kx ^ 1/x, x \to 0...

Comment: I should've said $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (kx)^{1/x}$ (treat $-at$ as $k$).

For $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} log (x)/x$, The numerator tends to $- \infty$. So, $log (x)/x \rightarrow -\infty$. Hence, $x^{1/x}= e^{log(x)/x} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.

So, you're left with $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} k^ {1/x}$. Again considering the logarithm of the limiting term.You can see that the limit approaches +$\infty$ as $x$ goes to $0$. You've +$\infty$ .0 scenario, which is why I said the whole thing is of indeterminate form.

Comment: Hence, you've to differentiate $-at (1-p)^{1/(1-p)}$ w.r.t $p$ & then consider the limit $p \rightarrow 1$ (This is equivalent to differentiate $(kx)^{1/x}$ w.r.t $x$ and then consider $x \rightarrow 0$).